# grant type not supported error unsupported_grant_type in android?

Tags: android, web-services

I am trying to call the service with parameters in post request,my parameters are grant_type="password", username="XXXXXX", password="yyyyyyy" and i got exception like  {"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}

And here i am sending request like below

```
String uri = Uri.parse(ServiceUrl.LOGIN_SERVER_URL)
                        .buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter("grant_type","password")
                        .appendQueryParameter("username",userName.getText().toString().trim())
                        .appendQueryParameter("password", urlEncoded)
                        .build().toString();
```

And my calling service code to get service response as:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static String httpPostQueryParamService(String Url) {

        String serveresponse = null;
        try {

        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,
                    ServiceUrl.timeoutConnection);
            // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
            // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams,
                    ServiceUrl.timeoutSocket);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(Url);

        request.addHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
            serveresponse = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_BAD_GATEWAY) {

                serveresponse = null;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return serveresponse;
        }
```

Comment: Isn't that stuff supposed to go into the body as `grant_type=password&username=username&password=password`?

Comment: Check my answer, I can't be certain but when I did it, I had to add it as a body.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add that stuff to the method body like so:

```
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true); 

// Add the body
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes("&grant_type=password&username=username&password=password");
wr.flush(); 
wr.close();
```

Comment: can u send me complete code how to send post parametres to the service??i am new to android.